# Создание файла на Python по pre-commit и commit

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, hook

Хочу сделать что бы по каждому комиту автоматически форматировался файл с номером версии. Сделал так

```
Patch="Patch="$PWD
PreCommit=$PWD/"Build/pre-commit.py $PWD"
python $PreCommit
exit 0
```

Но возникла проблема в том что сам файл с версии тоже надо держать в репозитории, что бы на другом рабочем месте версия ПО инкрементировалась

Файл с версиям создается комититься, но после комита модификация все равно остается, почему ? пробовал после python $PreCommit поставить задержку все равно так же.

Comment: Зачем вам это? Git в виде хеша уже хранит "версию".

Comment: Для встраиваемых системах, не LCD индикатор как-то не очень выводить хеш.

Answer (score 0):

Надо было добавить изменения.
Cделал так:

```
Patch="Patch="$PWD
PreCommit=$PWD/"Build/pre-commit.py $PWD"
python $PreCommit
git add Build\\SoftWare.txt
exit 0
```